# How do I open programs on a separate X screen?

Tags: nvidia

I'm using 11.04 and an nVidia video card with an HDMI out. I've got my TV hooked up to the HDMI out and have it set up to display a separate x screen. So far so good, I've got my separate x screen over there. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a program to open up over there, and not on the main display. If I use the variable "DISPLAY=:0.1" instead of opening the program on the TV, it just opens it on a second virtual desktop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

See the output of `pgrep -fl X`, it should be similar to

```
1284 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit 0 -novtswitch -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-aoiVzl/database -nolisten tcp vt7
```

You see `:0` is my DISPLAY, you should have two lines, the second with `:1`, so try `DISPLAY=:1` or `DISPLAY=:1.0`